# How increase size of attachment in Exchange 2013 via registry editor?

Tags: exchange, exchange-2013

Is it possible to change size of attachments in Exchange 2013 via registry editor? How can I find where is it? Is there any documentation where I can find how to change any value via registry editor?

I tried to change some values via PowerShell and monitor via process monitor but there are some many vaules and I couldn't find at all.

Answer (score 1):

Attachment size management isn't done through the registry, because it isn't a setting that is stored there. It is within Exchange. Very few of Exchange's settings are stored in the registry. 
Therefore to answer your question, no it is not possible to increase size of attachments through the registry. You need to use EMS. As such any change wouldn't show in Process Monitor, so you are wasting your time using that.

There are a number of places that you have to change the limit, at the transport level, at the org level and the mailbox level. 
This blog post is the best overview of what needs to be changed:
https://www.codetwo.com/admins-blog/exchange-attachment-size-limit-find-change/

Comment: thanks for the answer, but is there any config file where exchange keep configuration?

Comment: @whizzkid it's in the active directory database mostly, try adsiedit, or just use the exchange console

Comment: Why exactly is there a need to avoid using the commands to change the size?

Comment: My guess is that someone is trying to circumvent Corporate/IT policy. There's no reason to do this via the registry rather than the EMS.